# Java yaml path to current directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I'd like to start my Spring boot app with outer config files. I want to put new config file to directory where my jar file before start jar file.
I created an outer yaml:

```
myapp:
  src:
    ip: 111.22.333.444
```

and an inner yaml:

```
Spring:
  config:
     import: C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/application.yaml
```

If I khow my outer yaml path that works very well, but really I don't know path. I want to use path where my jar file started. What can I do for it?

Comment: Did you try specifying a relative path? What happens if you do?

Comment: I tryed 'classpath:' and '..' and '.' but app don't started because outer yaml is not found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to set the location of the yaml file, look in the documentation ==> [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

But in the usual case, you don't need to specify the location/path to the yaml file at all. It is enough that it is nearby (in the same folder as the jar file), Spring will find it itself

And delete the internal yaml file from the jar file, since you don't need it - Spring will use the external one

Comment: Unfortunately thats wrong. Application can't start if it haven't yalm file in resourses. Of course I looked all ways from docs before writing here, but there are not answer my quetion in docs.

Comment: Is your Spring application packed in a jar file working now?  If yes, just delete the configuration file from the jar file, put * .yaml to the same folder where the jar file is located, and run the jar. Everything will work.

Comment: I can't to remove config file when jar is ready, & I can't make jar without config file.

Comment: I didn't understand...   what is the problem with deleting any file from jar? A jar file is an ordinary archive.
Игорь, можешь написать / позвонить мне на https://t.me/YustasGo

Comment: Oh, you are was right. But I was starting my app from another directory. If I starting app from directory where app is located, your way works very well.